# Count numbers in range which sum of digits is same as product

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, for-loop, range

I have a big range of numbers (from 10^5 to 10^6) and I need to count all the numbers which sum of digits is same as product.

For example, 111126

- 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 6 = 12
- 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 2 * 6 = 12

I've tried using following code, which works fine, but very slow, because of big range of numbers.

```
result = 0

for num in range(x, y):
    num_str = str(num)
    summation = 0
    product = 1
    for j in range(len(num_str)):
        summation += int(num_str[j])
        product *= int(num_str[j])
        if j == len(num_str) - 1:
            if summation == product:
                result += 1
print(result)
```

Is there any way to count these numbers without using loops? And if not, how to make it run faster?

Comment: This is a [mathematical problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202679/sum-of-digits-and-product-of-digits-is-equal-3-digit-number). There's a [4 digit version](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227515/the-product-of-digits-equal-to-the-sum-of-digits) as well. Or a [blog post enumerating the options up to 10 digits](https://benvitalenum3ers.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/numbers-such-that-sum-of-their-digits-equal-to-product-of-digits/). Once you know there are only a limited number of digits that work you can easily produce all combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to brute-force this at all, as you can limit your search drastically.

- Any number with a 0 in it is going to result in the product being 0, while the sum is going to be > 0. Disregard such numbers.
- The digit order *doesn't matter*. The sum of `1 + 2` is the same as `2 + 1`, the same applies to their product.

Better to focus then on numbers with equal or incrementing digits, and if those digits sum up to the same value as the product you take all unique permutations of those numbers.

To produce the candidate numbers there are only 1287 permutations with replacement from 5 digits in the range 1 through to 9:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> len(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 5)))
1287
```

That's a much smaller search space:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, permutations
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

results = set()
for digits in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 5):
    if sum(digits) == reduce(mul, digits):
        # add unique permutations of the digits as a new integer
        results.update(int(''.join(map(str, p))) for p in permutations(digits))

for result in sorted(results):
    print(result)
```

This produces the 40 results in very little time indeed:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, permutations
>>> from operator import mul
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> results = set()
>>> for digits in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 5):
...     if sum(digits) == reduce(mul, digits):
...         results.update(int(''.join(map(str, p))) for p in permutations(digits))
... 
>>> len(results)
40
>>> for result in sorted(results):
...     print(result)
... 
11125
11133
11152
11215
11222
11251
11313
11331
11512
11521
12115
12122
12151
12212
12221
12511
13113
13131
13311
15112
15121
15211
21115
21122
21151
21212
21221
21511
22112
22121
22211
25111
31113
31131
31311
33111
51112
51121
51211
52111
```

The search can probably be further narrowed down; with some more [mathematical observations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227515/the-product-of-digits-equal-to-the-sum-of-digits) you can narrow down the search for those numbers with at least 2 `1` digits, for example, but the above is quite speedy already.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to speed up loops is to change them to numpy arrays, and do array operations instead of loops.  So if you got your numbers into a 2D numpy array and then did an array operation such as A==B and counted the trues in the new array it would normally be much quicker.

There may also be a better method than brute force.  I'm not clear about your range, as the example you give is outside of the range you give, but you can see that the maximum sum is 5x9 = 45.  You can immediately remove any that have sums that are primes bigger than 10.

For example, you could go through all the different possible products of 5 numbers *a,b,c,d,e*, such that *1<=b<=c<=d<=e<=9* and *abced<=45*.  When you find a solution, just work out the number of other similar solutions that are permutations of the one you've found.